# Step into subroutine call, but not calls made for parameters

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

```
func(a(), b.c)
```

When executing the line above in the pdb debugger, using `step` will actually step into `a`, and then into the getter for `b.c` if its atypical (such as being a `property`), before actually stepping into `func`.

Generally I find myself using `step` followed by `r` to return from the frames I'm not interested in, and often inexplicably pass over and miss the opportunity to `step` directly into `func`.

How do I step directly into `func`, or what sequence of debugger commands will guarantee that I end up in `func` rather than passing over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tb func` ("temporary break at func") followed by `c` ("continue") should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this by setting a break at the line number inside func that you're interested in, and then use continue. For example suppose your code looks like this:

```
110  def func(a1, a2):
111      "" docstring ""
112      first interesting line
```

then do this:

```
python -m pdb caller.py
pdb> b 112
pdb> c
```

Comment: This leaves a break at that line -- `tbreak` (the temporary break, that works just once), as I suggested earlier, seems closer to what the OP is asking.