# Step into function call in gdb but not calls for parameters

Tags: gdb

I would like to step into the function GDB is currently at, but not into the functions that are called to prepare the parameters for the call.

Is there a single command in gdb that steps over functions like `initial_metadata_flags()` and directly into `SendInitialMetadata`?

```
  void StartCallInternal() {
>   single_buf.SendInitialMetadata(&context_->send_initial_metadata_,
                                   context_->initial_metadata_flags());
  }
```

If there is, I did not see it mentioned here: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html

My current workaround is to `step`, `finish`, `step`, `finish`, until I get to the primary function on that line. But would like something more direct.

There are similar questions asked about [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270174/step-into-subroutine-call-but-not-calls-made-for-parameters) and [Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152299/how-can-i-step-directly-into-a-function-without-stepping-into-intermediate-funct), but I haven't found a good answer for gdb.

Comment: Would `tbreak single_buf.SendInitialMetadata` followed by `continue` come close to what you want?

Comment: Never found an answer to this. Let me know or post it here if you came to know!

Answer (score 0):

You can configure functions that you want to skip while stepping:

```
(gdb) help skip
Ignore a function while stepping.

Usage: skip [FUNCTION-NAME]
       skip [FILE-SPEC] [FUNCTION-SPEC]
If no arguments are given, ignore the current function.

FILE-SPEC is one of:
       -fi|-file FILE-NAME
       -gfi|-gfile GLOB-FILE-PATTERN
FUNCTION-SPEC is one of:
       -fu|-function FUNCTION-NAME
       -rfu|-rfunction FUNCTION-NAME-REGULAR-EXPRESSION
...
```