# How to step into a function but not its parameters using GDB

Tags: c++, gdb

As you may know, in GDB with `step(s)` command you can step into a function. But `s` examine and step into the function's parameters at first. For example for the following function:

```
foo(bar(1));
```

stepping into `foo`, steps into `bar` and then into `foo`. Stepping into the parameters become annoying as soon as the parameters count become more and more. Is it possible to directly step into `foo` execution and skip stepping into its parameters using GDB?

I know I can set a breakpoint for `foo` :) I'm searching for other solutions.

Comment: just single step it in such cases `si`

Comment: Was already asked several times: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60820583/72178, https://stackoverflow.com/q/29152299/72178, https://stackoverflow.com/q/3270174/72178.

Comment: @ks1322 None of their answers was not what answered in the comment.

Answer (score -1):

When dealing with some complex calls:

```
printf("%d %d\n", function(), next_function());
```

I "go to" with `step` to that line and then single step `si` into. It single steps into the first function called. Then you can `finish` to get out and `si` again into the next function.

Comment: I don't understand how this is the solution, since that's basically what he tried, but didn't want to do: `Stepping into the parameters become annoying as soon as the parameters count become more and more`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to ignore specific functions, use the skip command.  Eg.

```
skip bar
```

Now a line like:

```
foo(bar())
```

Will step directly into foo().

If there are files you know you don't want to debug into use the "skip file" command and then gdb will ignore them.  Eg.

> skip utilities.cpp

Then e.g.

```
foo(SomeUtilFunction())
```

Will step directly into foo

For one-off things, just set a breakpoint on foo and continue to stop at that function, skipping any argument functions etc.

To be clear: set a temporary breakpoint with:

```
   tb foo
```

Now "c" to continue will take you to the function, skipping any intermidiate calls for arguments etc.